# How we can upload documents Into a Salesforce CRM Content Personal Library using .net API?

Tags: rest-api, contentdocument, files

We are using trail account of sales force developer edition . We are trying to upload attachments into sales force account using REST API , In this scenario we can upload attachments into different sales force objects(Account,Notes & attachments,Document) using parent id but we can't upload attachments into Files in sales force . How we can upload attachments into the files in sales force ?

Comment: [Chatter REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_users_files_general.htm) might work for this scenario.

Comment: here is an example you can refer this,
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24671/upload-files-to-a-case-in-salesforce-via-rest-api